# Is there a more elegant way of implementing a background color on a link that by targetting the id?

Tags: css, menu

I want to make my wordpress menu items have 2 different background colors: one for the link and one for :hover. I'm a CSS beginner and found a solution but unfortunately it's not a good one because I target by the menu id generated by wordpress and if I delete the menu and create another one, that id will be gone and my styling will not work anymore.

Example:

```
menu-item-1212 a {
background-color:#fff;
}

menu-item-1212 a:hover{
background-color:#000;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve this so that no matter what id the first menu item will have, it will retain that background-color and the hover one?
I've searched online for an alternative and found :nth-child. I did tried to create something like this:(but it didn't worked)

```
#menu-secondary li a:nth-child(1) {
background-color:#fff;
}
#menu secondari li a:hover:nth-child(1) {
background-color:#000;
}
```

Will appreciate any suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Is 'secondari' a typo in the question? Or is that also a typo in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are targeting an anchor which is the nth child of li element. Each li only has one anchor probably. You need to target li as the nth child of the menu, like this:

```
#menu-secondary li:nth-child(1) a {
    background-color:#fff;
}
#menu secondari li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Ouch, seems like I didn't understood what I was targeting. Thank you very very very much!

Answer (score 1):

You won't even need `nth-child` if you are using a common background color and common hover color..

```
#menu-secondary li a {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

As you said you are not looking forward to use an id as it may be dynamic, than you can also select the elements using element selector if it's unique, like

```
div.class_name ul li a { /* class_name indicates your wrapper element class name */
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Also be sure you make your anchor tag `display: block;` if you want to cover up entire `li`